# base Class to all derived class c++ Qt

Tags: qt, c++11

I am having problem with getting the class names of all classes which are inherited from a base class.

```
Class Base
{
};
Class A:public Base
{
};
Class B:public Base
{
};
Class C:public Base
{
};
```

.....so on. My requirement is that I want to know all the class names which are inherited from class `Base`. Is there any way or method from base class that I can know all the classes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not in Qt. There might be code analysis tools out there, but I haven't used any.

Comment: @ddriver: Is there any method  in c++ ?

Comment: A simple word search ?

Comment: @Thomas - that would return any reference to the class name, which might not necessary be inheritance. Some regex patterns can be employed to narrow down the results.

Comment: @ddriver looking for `public Base` should not return any reference to the class name.

Comment: You can use Qt meta information (QMetaObject and so on) but Base in this case should be subclass of QObject or did I misunderstand something and you need something like doxygen to generate inheritance tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt allows to do this with the following limitations:

- All involved classes should be derived from `QObject`.
- Each class should be registered in a global class list. Qt doesn't provide a way to get full list of classes.

Meta information about a `QObject`-derived class is stored in a `QMetaObject` that can be accessed via `T::staticMetaObject`. First of all, you want to have a list of all metaobjects in your application. You can use something like this:

```
QList<const QMetaObject*> global_list;
template<class T> register_class() {
  global_list << &T::staticMetaObject;
}

//execute the following at program initialization
register_class<Base>();
register_class<A>();
register_class<B>();
register_class<C>();
```

To get list of class names derived from Base, you need to:

1. Get `const QMetaObject*` of the target class as &Base::staticMetaObject.
2. Iterate over global list of metaobjects and check if `QMetaObject::​superClass` returns target meta object. You may need to perform recursive check if indirect inheritance should also be detected.
3. Get names of found subclasses with `QMetaObject::​className`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
but My base Class does not inherit from `QObject`
Is there any generic method in C++ ?
how i can get all the class name..
can you please provide an example that will be very helpful.
thanks.

Comment: No, there is no reflection in C++.

Comment: @ Pavel Strakhov :Thanks for the info.